# passed invalid types

Tags: fortran

```
A = test (a, z'00000000')
```

and `test` is:

```
integer function test(a, m)
    integer, intent(in) :: a
    integer, intent(in) :: m
end function test
```

Error:

```
Type mismatch in argument 'm' at (1): passed INTEGER(16) to INTEGER(4)
```

Comment: Which compiler and compiler version?

Comment: You're running this code _somehow_, otherwise you wouldn't be getting an error, so remember to mention (ideally in your post) how you're running it =)

Comment: Compiler details are relevant because this isn't valid Fortran code, relying on compiler extensions.

Answer (score 4):

No, `z'00000000'` is not an integer, it's a typeless sequence of bits. The Fortran language does not define what it means when you pass a BOZ constant as an actual argument to a user-defined procedure. This leaves compilers free to invent their own interpretation, and as you might expect, they don't always agree.

Fortran 202x will significantly expand the contexts in which a BOZ constant may appear, but your use is not one of them. The correct fix for this is to pass `INT(z'00000000')` - this is "default integer" and will do what you want.

Further detail is in my post [Doctor Fortran in “We’re All BOZos on This Bus”](https://stevelionel.com/drfortran/2020/08/11/doctor-fortran-in-were-all-bozos-on-this-bus/).

Comment: It's fine. Thanks.